# Ruby: provide an argument while turning proc to a block

Tags: ruby

We can easily define a method and turn it into block with unary ampersand.

```
def my_method(arg)
  puts arg*2
end

['foo', 'bar'].each(&method(:my_method))

# foofoo
# barbar

# or
my_method = ->(arg) { puts arg*2 }
['foo', 'bar'].each(&my_method)
# same output
```

As we see the first argument is passed automatically when we work with aggregates. But what if we need to pass 2 or even more arguments?

```
my_method = ->(arg,num) { puts arg*num }
['foo', 'bar'].each(&my_method)
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
['foo', 'bar'].each(&my_method(3))
# NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for main:Object
['foo','bar'].each do |i, &my_method|
  yield i, 3
end
# LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
```

Is that possible to pass additional arguments while turning proc to a block?

Comment: Do you want both arguments to be passed from the called method by yielding, or do you want to specify one argument when submitting the block to the method?

Comment: Just to note that `['foo', 'bar'].each(&my_method)` wouldn't make sense as `each` will always yield just one element. Not answering your question, but check out `['foo', 3].each_slice(2, &my_method)`.

Comment: I think that `curry` might be a key to this question.

Comment: Just to point it out, `my_method` is not really a method, it is a function, which is why this might be confusing in the first place.

Comment: @Drenmi: You mean lambda right? :)

Comment: @fylooi: In the very first example, it is `def my_method`, so I chose function as a general term for everything not a method. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808431/ruby-provide-an-argument-while-turning-proc-to-a-block#comment57360564_34808802):

> Strange, but it swaps arguments during the performance

Actually, the argument order *is* preserved.

`curry` returns a new proc that effectively collects arguments until there are enough arguments to invoke the original method / proc (based on its arity). This is achieved by returning intermediate procs:

```
def foo(a, b, c)
  { a: a, b: b, c: c }
end

curried_proc = foo.curry  #=> #<Proc:0x007fd09b84e018 (lambda)>
curried_proc[1]           #=> #<Proc:0x007fd09b83e320 (lambda)>
curried_proc[1][2]        #=> #<Proc:0x007fd09b82cfd0 (lambda)>
curried_proc[1][2][3]     #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

You can pass any number of arguments at once to a curried proc:

```
curried_proc[1][2][3]     #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
curried_proc[1, 2][3]     #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
curried_proc[1][2, 3]     #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
curried_proc[1, 2, 3]     #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Empty arguments are ignored:

```
curried_proc[1][][2][][3] #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

However, you obviously can't alter the argument order.

---

An alternative to currying is *partial application* which returns a new proc with lower arity by fixing one or more arguments. Unlike `curry`, there's no built-in method for partial application, but you can easily write your own:

```
my_proc = -> (arg, num) { arg * num }

def fix_first(proc, arg)
  -> (*args) { proc[arg, *args] }
end

fixed_proc = fix_first(my_proc, 'foo')  #=> #<Proc:0x007fa31c2070d0 (lambda)>
fixed_proc[2]  #=> "foofoo"
fixed_proc[3]  #=> "foofoofoo"

[2, 3].map(&fixed_proc) #=> ["foofoo", "foofoofoo"]
```

Or fixing the last argument:

```
def fix_last(proc, arg)
  -> (*args) { proc[*args, arg] }
end

fixed_proc = fix_last(my_proc, 2)  #=> #<Proc:0x007fa31c2070d0 (lambda)>
fixed_proc['foo']  #=> "foofoo"
fixed_proc['bar']  #=> "barbar"

['foo', 'bar'].map(&fixed_proc) #=> ["foofoo", "barbar"]
```

---

Of course, you are not limited to fixing single arguments. You could for example return a proc that takes an array and converts it to an argument list:

```
def splat_args(proc)
  -> (array) { proc[*array] }
end

splatting_proc = splat_args(my_proc)
[['foo', 1], ['bar', 2], ['baz', 3]].map(&splatting_proc)
#=> ["foo", "barbar", "bazbazbaz"]
```

Answer (score 7):

@sawa is right. You can do that with `curry`.

Proc version:

```
mult = proc {|a, b| a * b} # => #<Proc:0x00000002af1098@(irb):32>
[1, 2].map(&mult.curry[2])  # => [2, 4]
```

Method version:

```
def mult(a, b)
  a*b
end

[1, 2].map(&method(:mult).to_proc.curry[2])  # => [2, 4]
```

Comment: Your last line references the local variable `mult` that was assigned in the first line, not the method.

Comment: @Stefan: Good catch.

Comment: You could use `[1, 2].map(&method(:mult).to_proc.curry[2])`, although it looks cumbersome.

Comment: @Stefan: Yeah, just figured it out, was trying to find a shorter version. Very cumbersome indeed.

Comment: Strange, but it swaps arguments during the performance:
`foo = -> (a,b) { puts "a: #{a}, b: #{b}"}`
`['foo', 'bar'].each(&foo.curry[2])`
`# a: 2, b: foo`
`# a: 2, b: bar`

Comment: @DreamWalker currying "fixes" the first argument, not the last, i.e. `proc.curry[a][b]` is equivalent to `proc[a, b]`