# Currying a proc with keyword arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, currying

Say I have a generic `Proc`, `Lambda` or `method` which takes an optional second argument:

```
pow = -> (base, exp: 2) { base**exp }
```

Now I want to curry this function, giving it an `exp` of `3`.

```
cube = pow.curry.call(exp: 3)
```

There's an ambiguity here, arising from the keyword arguments and the new hash syntax, where Ruby interprets `exp: 3` as a hash being passed as the first argument, `base`. This results in the function immediately being invoked, rendering a `NoMethodError` when `#**` is sent to the hash.

---

Setting a default value for the first argument will similarly result in the function being immediately invoked when currying, and if I mark the first argument as required, without providing a default:

```
pow = -> (base:, exp: 2) { base**exp }
```

the interpreter will complain that I'm missing argument `base` when I attempt to curry the `Proc`.

---

How can I curry a function with the second argument?

Comment: To fix an arbitrary positional argument, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34813268/477037

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could build your own keyword-flavored curry method that collects keyword arguments until the required parameters are present. Something like:

```
def kw_curry(method)
  -> (**kw_args) {
    required = method.parameters.select { |type, _| type == :keyreq }
    if required.all? { |_, name| kw_args.has_key?(name) }
      method.call(**kw_args)
    else
      -> (**other_kw_args) { kw_curry(method)[**kw_args, **other_kw_args] }
    end
  }
end

def foo(a:, b:, c: nil)
  { a: a, b: b, c: c }
end

proc = kw_curry(method(:foo))
proc[a: 1]              #=> #<Proc:0x007f9a1c0891f8 (lambda)>
proc[b: 1]              #=> #<Proc:0x007f9a1c088f28 (lambda)>
proc[a: 1, b: 2]        #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>nil}
proc[b: 2][a: 1]        #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>nil}
proc[a: 1, c: 3][b: 2]  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

The example above is limited to keyword arguments only, but you can certainly extend it to support both, keyword arguments and positional arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sample implementation @stefan! I was thinking along these lines, too, but I was planning to name it `#scurry`. :-P

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can do it with `Proc.curry`, but there is always the longhand way

```
cube = -> (base) {pow.(base, exp: 3)}
```

You could also create a factory function

```
pow_factory = -> (exp) {-> (base) {pow.(base, exp: exp)}}
cube = pow_factory.(3)
```

Comment: The idea of using a factory function is definitely interesting! :-)

Answer (score 2):

- `curry` does not work with keyword arguments. A curried function is getting one parameter at a time, which is conceptually incompatible with "any order is fine" keyword arguments.
- `curry` must know the exact arity. If you just call `curry` with no arguments, it will ignore any optionals (in case of `pow = -> (base, exp=2) { base**exp }`, same as `curry(1)`). Use `curry(2)` to force both parameters. A curried function can't know an optional parameter is following, and read the future to determine if it should execute or return a curried continuation.

Comment: Okay. Consider the second argument is not optional. How (if at all) can I curry starting from the second argument? :-)

Comment: AFAIK, again not possible. `curry` will allow you to supply the arguments in the same order that they stand in the function signature. If you want to curry `x.(a, b)` into `xc.(b).(a)`, you will have to write your own: `xc = -> (b, a) { x.(a, b) }.curry`, or `xc = -> (b) { -> (a) { x.(a, b) } }`. Otherwise, I don't know how you would communicate the desired parameter order to `curry`.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [@Stefan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34870825/4352306) here a solution that includes all the arguments:

```rb
# @param meth [Method, Proc, Lambda]
# @param on_missing [Symbol] what should do when there are missing required arguments
#   - `:curry`   -> it does a curry with the parameters received (default).
#   - `:call`    -> it calls anyway (will error).
#   - `:safe`    -> it sets to `nil` the missing required arguments and does a call.
#   - `:return`  -> it returns `nil` but doesn't call.
def curry(meth, on_missing = :curry)
  -> (*args, **kargs, &block) do
    params    = meth.parameters
    kparams   = params.select  { |type, _| (type == :keyreq) || (type == :key) }
    aparams   = params.select  { |type, _| (type == :req)    || (type == :opt) }

    kreq_miss = kparams.select { |type, _| type == :keyreq }.map(&:last) - kargs.keys
    req_miss  = aparams.select { |type, _| type == :req    }.count       - args.count
    req_miss  = req_miss >= 0 ? req_miss : 0
    ready     = kreq_miss.empty? && req_miss == 0

    if on_missing == :safe
      unless params.find { |type, _| type == :keyrest }
        (kargs.keys - kparams.map(&:last)).each { |name| kargs.delete(name) }
      end
      unless params.find { |type, _| type == :rest    }
        args = args[0..(aparams.count-1)] if args.count > aparams.count
      end
      unless ready
        kreq_miss.each { |name| kargs[name] = nil }
        args  = args.dup.push(*Array.new(req_miss, nil))
        ready = true
      end
    end
    return meth.call(*args, **kargs, &block) if ready || on_missing == :call
    return nil                               if on_missing == :return
    # (default) on_missing == :curry
    -> (*oth, **koth, &blk) do
      curried = curry(meth, on_missing)
      curried[*args, *oth, **kargs, **koth, &(blk || block)]
    end
  end
end
```

**Usage Example**

```rb
def foo(a, b = :default, c:, d: :default)
  args = { 'a' => a, 'b' => b, c: c, d: d }
  yield(args) if block_given?
  "foo called!"
end

bar = curry(method(:foo))["bar", d: "override"] {|r| pp r}
bar.call(c: "now")
# {"a"=>"bar", "b"=>:default, :c=>"now", :d=>"override"}
# => "foo called!"
curry(method(:foo), :safe)["bar", d: "override"] {|r| pp r}
# {"a"=>"bar", "b"=>:default, :c=>nil, :d=>"override"}
# => "foo called!"
curry(method(:foo), :return)["bar", d: "override"] {|r| pp r}
# => nil
curry(method(:foo), :call)["bar", d: "override"] {|r| pp r}
# ArgumentError (missing keyword: :c)
```

**Overloading arguments**

```rb
curry(method(:foo), :safe).call("bar", "baz", "ignored", d: "override", z: "ignored") {|r| pp r}
# {"a"=>"bar", "b"=>"baz", :c=>nil, :d=>"override"}
# => "foo called!"
bar = curry(method(:foo))["bar", d: "override"]
bar = bar["override", z: "bad"] {|r| pp r}
bar.call(c: "call it")
# ArgumentError (unknown keyword: :z)
```