# Collecting keyword arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, keyword-argument

Just trying to understand how to collect arguments in Ruby, I came up with the following snippet, that seems to fail to collect `keyword arguments` in `**kargs` in some case:

```
def foo(i, j= 9, *args, k: 11, **kargs)
  puts "args: #{args}; kargs: #{kargs}"
end

foo(a: 7, b: 8)
# output: args: []; kargs: {}
foo(9, a: 7, b: 8)
# output: args: []; kargs: {:a=>7, :b=>8}
foo(9, 10, 13, a: 7, b: 8)
# output: args: [13]; kargs: {:a=>7, :b=>8}
```

I would like to know why it does not collect `kargs` in the first call to `foo`, while in the second call it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the first parameter `i`, is a required parameter (no default value), so, the first value passed to the method (in your first example, this is the hash `{a: 7, b: 8}`) is stored into it.

Then, since everything else is optional, the remaining values (if any, in this example, there are none) are filled in, as applicable. IE, the second parameter will go to `j`, unless it is a named parameter, then it goes to `kargs` (or `k`). The third parameter, and any remaining--up until the first keyword argument, go into `args`, and then any keyword args go to `kargs`

```
def foo(i, j= 9, *args, k: 11, **kargs)
  puts "i: #{i}; args: #{args}; kargs: #{kargs}"
end

foo(a: 7, b: 8)
# i: {:a=>7, :b=>8}; args: []; kargs: {}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. I though that would only happen if I called by `foo({a: 7, b: 8})`. Perhaps that is a Ruby way to avoid an error when you call?

Comment: is there a way to avoid that to happen? I am trying to build a `curry` function that includes both: `*args` and `**kw_args`. Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51699428/4352306)

Comment: I have not tested it yet, but from what I read in `Ruby 3` it should fail to run `foo(a: 7, b: 8)`. Is that right?